# How I restrict user authentication for some group for SAML client in Keycloak?

Tags: authentication, authorization, keycloak, saml-2.0, openid-connect

I have a **Keycloak 7.0.0**. I need to setup SSO for different applications (SAML 2.0 and OpenID Connect). The setup must provide me to restrict/allow access to each application individually.

I read a lot of documentation, and did not found any information that I needed about restriction on Keycloak side, only for application side requesting access.

I tried some solution from other posts on StackOverflow, but it did not work for me (maybe I did mistake in configuration).

So my question is in subject... How to restrict user authentication for some group for SAML clients in Keycloak? Probably it means '**Authorize**', but I did not found any of 'Authorization' section for SAML.